# Magento 2: Create a Custom Header

Tags: magento2

I am trying to design a custom home page. How to create a custom header in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create an XML file on the following path as below

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="custom_header"/>
        <move element="top.search" as="topsearch" destination="custom_header"/>
        <move element="minicart" as="minicart" destination="custom_header"/>
        <move element="store_language" as="store_language" destination="custom_header" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2: Create an HTML file on the following path as below

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/customheader.phtml

Place this line in the code file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("store_language"); ?>
```

**Hope this helps!**